How to launch a GUI-application from terminal while keeping the terminal on the front and the cursor on terminal
Let's say I want to launch an application from the terminal but I want to keeping the terminal on the front and the cursor on terminal
e.g.
$ mupdf somepdffile.pdf

Is there a way to do it?

As long as you're in a graphical context, and don't plan to close your shell right away,  the old, traditional & will do the trick.
mupdf somepdffile.pdf &
mupdfpid=$!

I'm having you save the PID of the backgrounded process in case you need it later (e.g. kill -HUP $mupdfpid;sleep 2;kill -KILL $mupdfpid )
